# Why git branch without any ancestor

Tags: git, git-branch

Yesterday afternoon a college of mine did the git commit seen in the picture below. I wonder how you can do such strange things in git. Normally, every branch should have an ancestor branch that exists before. At least in my understanding of git.

How is this git history possible to get and why should this be useful?

[image: Strange Git branch]

Comment: "*every branch should have an ancestor branch that exists before*" - Then how the first branch was ever created?

Comment: The first branch does not have an ancestor. Thats correct. But all branches after the first should have an ancestor.

Comment: @FluepkeSchaeng Why? A branch can even have **more** than one ancestor. Git is really flexible, if you can imagine it, you can do it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But all branches after the first should have an ancestor.

No: you can create one or more **orphan** branch at any time with

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

In your case, check the history of the `4-x-dev-cam` branch on the remote repo side, and see if its history starts with a commit without parent.

> why should this be useful

- The repo git itself has at least one orphan branch (beside `master`): the [`todo` branch](https://github.com/git/git/tree/todo), in order to keep management scripts which are not part of the git sources themselves.
- Any [GitHub page projects](https://pages.github.com/) has at least another orphan branch (beside `master`): [`gh-pages`](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/#create-a-gh-pages-branch), in order to manage an website associated to your project.

Basically, any time you need, in the same repo, to manage a content which is orthogonal to your main project (management script, website to illustrate your project, ...), an orphan branch is a good way to isolate that secondary history.

In the case of the `4-x-dev-cam`, one possible explanation would be a massive rewrite of the project, starting from scratch.
In that case, an orphan branch is also a good way to separate that new history from the previous branches.

Comment: This explains, how you can get such a commit history. Thank you for your quick answer. In which particular cases should it be useful to create an orphan branch?

Comment: @FluepkeSchaeng Hide part of your history from a  public repository, for example. From [Git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.7.3.1): "*This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise encumbered bits of code.*"

Comment: @FluepkeSchaeng I have added two concrete examples of more than one orphan branch.

Comment: Thats exactly what i searched for. :)